# C# input string was not in a correct format when no entered value to a textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am using a `SqlCommand` to insert values in a row of a SQL Server table. It works perfectly fine when I insert a text to all my textbox but whenever there is a blank textbox, I always get this error

> Input string was not in a correct format

Here is my code

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save this book?", "Saving Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
      cn.Open();

      cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblBook (bkISBN, bkTitle, bkEdition, bkGenre, bkMediaType, bkLanguage, bkAuthor, bkPublisher, bkPrice, bkDate) VALUES (@ISBN, @booktitle, @edition, @genre, @mediatype, @language, @author, @publisher, @price, @date)", cn);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", txtISBN.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booktitle", txtTitle.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edition", txtEdition.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", txtGenre.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mediatype",cboMediaType.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", txtLanguage.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtAuthor.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", txtPublisher.Text);
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", int.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
      cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dtCreated.Text);

      cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cn.Close();

      MessageBox.Show("Record has been successfully saved!");
      Clear();
      frmlist.LoadRecords();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Any help to fix this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is `Price` meant to be an integer value from a textbox? Usually prices are `SqlDbType.Money`/`System.Decimal` or Integer Cents (i.e. parsed decimal value multiplied by 100) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem line:

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", int.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
```

The `Int32.Parse` method will throw a `FormatException` if it cannot parse the value.

Use `Int32.TryParse` (with appropriate `CultureInfo`!) instead:

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Int32.TryParse( txtPrice.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, NumberStyles.Currency, out Int32 priceValue ) ? priceValue : DBNull.Value);
```

That said, [don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)!

Comment: I am new to programming and I'll try to practice not using AddWithValue when inserting a value. Thank you so much for the help